# Transforming a multivariate normal

Tags: probability

[image]

[image]

I don't understand where the part underlined in green comes from.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{Y} 
$$
Such that
$$
x_{i} = c_{ij}y_{j}
$$
Here $c_{ij} = [\mathbf{M}^{-1}]_{ij}$.
So now you can see where the derivative comes from?